# Is it possible to enable MoveToPoint and SnapToTick in VBA for slider in MS Access 2007 Form? Also slider default value?

Tags: ms-access, vba, slider

I have a form in MS Access 2007 where I have a slider working, but the interface is not what it needs to be. I inserted the slider using ActiveX MS Slider Control 6.0 (SP4).

You can click and drag on the mouse and that works to set the value. But you can't click near a tick mark to set the value. My slider goes from minimum 1 to maximum 5. If the thumb is at 1, and I point at 2 and click, the thumb jumps to 5.

Also, my thumb starts at 1 every time I open the form, which corresponds to "Strongly disagree." I'd like the thumb to start at 3 every time the form opens, so that the user isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `LargeChange` to be 1 to make the click move only 1 per time
set `Value` to be 3 to set the default value to set the slider in the middle
[image]

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks so much for the answer!!! The Value property is exactly what I wanted, awesome!!! Changing the LargeChange helps, but since it just moves from one tick to the next, it's not quite what I was looking for. For example if the thumb is on 1 and I click on 4, the thumb moves to 2. Click on 4 again and it moves to 3. What I'd like is to have it move straight to 4 when I click on 4. Would this be possible using VBA? Thanks again Sean!!!

Comment: your only chance would be to use the `MouseDown` event. Note that Access does not show all the events in the properties window, but if you get into the VBA windows, and go to your slider control in the first dropdown above the code window, then the other dropdown should show you all the events the control supports

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you!! For some reason I can't login remotely tonight from home, so I can't work on this but I'll check it out tomorrow. Thanks again!!

Comment: Sorry I thought I'd definitely be able to login remotely tonight because I logged out before leaving, but it's still not working. I will take this laptop in with me tomorrow and fix the problem. (I never have time to work on this project AT work this week, unfortunately).

Comment: You were right, @Sean, MouseDown worked to simulate the SnapToTick effect. Below is what I think has ended up working. The divided by 5 is because I have 1 - 5 for the tick values. The x seems to be dependent on the distance from the left edge of the slider itself.  ...      
Private Sub Slider_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)

Me.Slider.Value = x / (Me.Slider.Width / 5)

End Sub
Thanks again Sean for the help!!! I hope this helps someone else using Access 2007 (if anyone still does these days, besides my job!)